# How to Setup TFS(Team Foundation Server) and Visual Studio 2017

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

Firstly,I was used TFS(Team Foundation Server) and Visual Studio 2015 in my previous project.In this project,My leader setup the TFS and I just used it and it is very nice to use.

Now i am developing new project with Visual Studio 2017 and I want to use TFS.I was googled but not clear for me.So Please Let me known,where can i see clear step by step setup guide of TFS with Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: What about this issue? Could you get useful information from Tingting and Richard's suggestions?

Comment: sorry for my late reply, I just handover with other project.Please let me ask a question. As the requirement of this=> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements , Can i use tfs on window 7 pro?

Comment: You want to install TFS on Windows 7 or connect TFS on Windows 7? Connecting TFS from Windows 7 server is supported. And we don't suggest you to install TFS 2017/2018 on Windows 7 machine. You'd better user Windows Server operation system.

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio includes all the client pieces for TFS in the default install.

So all you need to do is go to the Team menu to connect to the TFS server. The URL will depend on the configuration of the server: get this from the Admin. (For VSTS it will be `your-account.visualstudio.com`.)

There is a [new user's guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/user-guide/) which should help with the details.

Comment: Thanks you,i will check this.

Answer (score -1):

So you want to add the new solution which is created in VS 2017 into TFS. Please follow the steps below:

1. [Connect to your team project in VS 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/user-guide/connect-team-projects#connect-from-visual-studio-or-team-explorer).
2. Add your solution to source control. Refer to [Add a existing app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/share-your-code-in-tfvc-vs#add-an-existing-app).
3. Check your new project into TFS.

Comment: Thanks you,i will check this.

Answer (score -1):

Hi you just go to the team Explorer and using the admin rights link add the TFS that u want to use.

And from source control you can get the files of the project.
Hope this will work @Jze